# As3 Movieclip background image size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, box2d

I am working with box2d, and generating a few grounds of variable size (all rectangles). The image the grounds use is 500px by 200px, however, when I create and size my grounds, the background image stretches to fill the body. I am trying to have it aligned to top left and just tile with no resizing but am really unsure of how to control it.

I imported the image as a movieclip to my library, if it helps, and also have a basic empty class for it (EarthGround.as). I've been doing a little research but really haven't found anything definitive about manipulating the movieclips associated image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be specific with that. Maybe a screen shot would help.

Until then, possible causes could be:

- Box2D uses real world values where 1 pixel = 1 meter. You have to
  choose a scale factor.
- Box2d uses the center of any object as its registration point. You
  should always do the same with your flash sprite/movieclip, to keep
  it simple.

Comment: I have the center registration point.  Without it the graphic itself did not align to the actual ground itself.  The problem is how it is scaling the image, rather than just allowing it to repeat like a tile.

Comment: Open the movie clip & scale the image inside it. You create separate box2d object for each tile. For 1 movieclip, 1 box2d object.